# How to fix text going bottom in HTML & CSS?

Tags: html, css

When I try to text something bit in my second div, this text is coming bottom and the page's structure is abolished.

The main text and left div are not in line and when I try to a shorter page, the main text is going down and It's very plain, but when I add small text, it gets normally. 
Can I fix that?

```css
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}

.tutorial_links {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(200, 201, 201);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Sylfaen";
  line-height: 26px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.list_div {
  background-color: rgb(19, 19, 19);
  height: 300px;
}

.tutorial_list {
  line-height: 32px;
}

.title {
  color: rgb(200, 201, 201);
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="list_div inline">
  <h1 class="title">
    Python კურსები
  </h1>

  <ul class="tutorial_list">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="tutorial_links">Python მთავარი</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#" class="tutorial_links">Python სინტაქსი</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#" class="tutorial_links">Python ბეჭდვა</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div class="main_text inline">
  <div>
    <span class="pythonNameColor">Python
      <span class="pythonGeorgianText">მთავარი</span>
    </span>

    <hr width="1000px">

    <p class="regular_text">
      Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. <br> It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia,
      looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please rewrite this `When I try to text something bit in my second div, this text is coming bottom and the page's structure is abolished.` it is not understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think the issue may stem from your use of `display:inline-block` and setting your hr's width to 1000px. The hr's width seems to be the only element with a set width.

Use `display:flex` instead of `display:inline-block` which will give you a lot more flexibility and control over your layout.

I'd also add this to your css:

```
body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
```

**Updated after clarification:**
In order to get your div's to line up next to each other, wrap them both in a parent div and call it 'container' then add justify-content to each child div.

Here's a great resource for using and understanding Flexbox: [CSS Tricks Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

You can also check out this [codepen that I created](https://codepen.io/grant-k-dev/pen/QWmbYGJ)

```
// index.html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='list-div'>
   your content
  </div>
  <div class='main-text'>
   your content
  </div>
</div>
```

```
//styles.css

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.list-div {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.main-text {
 justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I want that my list_div will be in the left position and main_text in right, it's like some kind of programming tutorial web page accomplishing

Comment: You want one div on the right and the other on the left?

Comment: yes, like on this site: 
https://www.w3schools.com/python/default.asp

Comment: I updated my answer. If it solves your problem, please mark it as answered.